# Freeform XML configuration section body in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

Is there a way to make a configuration section that would allow a freeform XML body? How would I get that freeform body in code?

For example I'd like to create a ModuleConfigurationSection like this:

```
<modules>
    <module name="ModuleA" type="My.Namespace.ModuleA, My.Assembly">
        <moduleConfig>
            <serviceAddress>http://myserver/myservice.svc</serviceAddress>
        </moduleConfig>
    </module>
    <module name="ModuleB" type="My.Namespace.ModuleB, My.OtherAssembly">
        <moduleConfig>
            <filePath>c:\directory</filePath>
        </moduleConfig>
    </module>
</modules>
```

So some code would spin up each of these module types from config sections using `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("modules")` and I'd like to pass the XML inside the  `moduleConfig` element as an opaque configuration value to the constructor of the module class.

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I ended up accomplishing this:

```
public class ModuleElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    XElement _config;
    public XElement Config
    {
        get { return _config;  }
    }

    protected override bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(string elementName, System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (elementName == "config")
        {
            _config = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return base.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(elementName, reader);
    }
}
```

So the xml would look like:

```
<module name="ModuleA">
    <config>
        <filePath>C:\files\file.foo</filePath>
    </config>
</module>
```

The body of the config element could be any freeform xml that you like. Assuming that you set up a collection, when you do `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("modules")` you can then access the `Config` property of each `ModuleElement` object as an XElement representing the XML of the config element node.

Answer (score 1):

In my application I could not use the .NET 3.5 Framework. I used a slightly different approach and came up with this piece of code:

```
public class ModuleSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    private const string ELEMENT_NAME_CONFIG = "config";

    private XmlNode _configNode;

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    public XmlNode Config
    {
        get { return _configNode; }
    }

    protected override bool OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(string elementName, XmlReader reader)
    {
        if(elementName.Equals(ELEMENT_NAME_CONFIG, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
            // Add the unrecognized element.
            _configNode = _xmlDocument.ReadNode(reader);
            return true;
        } else {
            return base.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(elementName, reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to curry away the `XmlNode` for the element that you want just like in my answer where I save the `XElement`. I updated your code to show this.